# react-native expo app is working on emulator but build is failing

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, symlink

I'm using react-native to build mobile application (android/IOS) and react application for web version. Since a lot of code will be shared between the 2 I'm using monorepo architecture for this.Below is my file structure

```
├── hybrid-frontend
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── android
│   ├── app.json
│   ├── assets
│   ├── babel.config.js
│   ├── eas.json
│   ├── ios
│   ├── metro.config.js
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   └── shared-frontend -> ../shared-frontend
├── shared-frontend
│   └── helloWorld.js
└── webapp-frontend
    ├── README.md
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── public
    ├── shared-frontend -> ../shared-frontend
    └── src
```

shared-frontend folder contains the files which will be shared between react app(webapp-frontend) and react-native app(hybrid-frontend)
I'm using the latest react-native version 0.72.5 which has support for symlinks. I've added symlinks to shared-frontend folder in project's root directory as well as node_modules folder. When I run `npx expo start` I'm able to see output in both android as well as ios simulator. When I run `eas build -p android`  to build and generate an apk file I'm getting error.
Below are my files

App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import helloWorldText from './shared-frontend/helloWorld';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{helloWorldText}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "hybrid-frontend",
    "slug": "hybrid-frontend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.companyname.ios-app"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.companyname.app"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "21defe68-4107-42e6-9118-cd4d395e9951"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

eas.json

```
{
    "build": {
      "preview": {
        "android": {
          "buildType": "apk"
        }
      },
      "preview2": {
        "android": {
          "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
        }
      },
      "preview3": {
        "developmentClient": true
      },
      "production": {}
    }
  }
```

metro.config.js

```
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const path = require('path');

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
const config = {
    // ...
    watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..')],
    resolver: {
      unstable_enableSymlinks: true,
      unstable_enablePackageExports: true,
    },
    transformer: {
      assetPlugins: ['expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles'],
    },
  };


module.exports = config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hybrid-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~49.0.13",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

shared-frontend/helloWorld.js

```
const helloWorldText = "Hello, World! This is Person Name";
export default helloWorldText;
```

error from expo build

```
> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

[stderr] 

Error: Unable to resolve module ./shared-frontend/helloWorld from /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.js: 

[stderr] 

None of these files exist:

[stderr] 

  * shared-frontend/helloWorld(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)

[stderr] 

  * shared-frontend/helloWorld/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)

[stderr] 

  1 | import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

[stderr] 

  2 | import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

[stderr] 

> 3 | import helloWorldText from './shared-frontend/helloWorld';

[stderr] 

    |                             ^

[stderr] 

  4 |

[stderr] 

  5 | export default function App() {

[stderr] 

  6 |   return (

[stderr] 

Error: Unable to resolve module ./shared-frontend/helloWorld from /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.js: 

[stderr] 

None of these files exist:

[stderr] 

  * shared-frontend/helloWorld(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)

[stderr] 

  * shared-frontend/helloWorld/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)

[stderr] 

  1 | import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

[stderr] 

  2 | import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

[stderr] 

> 3 | import helloWorldText from './shared-frontend/helloWorld';

[stderr] 

    |                             ^

[stderr] 

  4 |

[stderr] 

  5 | export default function App() {

[stderr] 

  6 |   return (

[stderr] 

    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:114:15)

[stderr] 

    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:277:43)

[stderr] 

    at Object.resolve (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:169:21)

[stderr] 

    at Graph._resolveDependencies (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:473:35)

[stderr] 

    at Graph._processModule (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:261:38)

[stderr] 

    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

[stderr] 

    at async Graph._addDependency (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:372:20)

[stderr] 

    at async Promise.all (index 2)

[stderr] 

    at async Graph._processModule (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:322:5)

[stderr] 

    at async Graph._traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:249:5)

> Task :expo-modules-core:generateReleaseRFile

151 actionable tasks: 151 executed

[stderr] 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[stderr] 

* What went wrong:

[stderr] 

Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

[stderr] 

> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

[stderr] 

* Try:

[stderr] 

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr] 

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr] 

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr] 

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr] 

BUILD FAILED in 3m 5s

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

Since symlinks feature is recent, not much documentation is available about it. IOS build is also failing